# Do I need friction modifier for rear differential oil 75W 140 for an F150 2005?

Tags: f-150, rear-differential

I have a 2005 F150 Lariat 5.4L V8 4x4 3.73 axle ratio, I'll perform rear differential maintenance and bought the fluids at the dealership. The OEM manual says the fluid needed is 75W-90, although the dealer says new fluid is 75W-140 and that I need friction modifier.

Do I really need the friction modifier for this differential type? Or is it safe to use 75W-140 without the friction modifier?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! usually a friction modifier is needed if you have a limited slip differential (LSD). I realize *most* 4x4's have them, but you'd have to check to make sure. The reason (as I understand it) for the friction modifier is to prevent the LSD from chattering or making noise. Agree with jwh20 about the weight of gear oil ... if the manufacture states 75W-90, that's what I'd go with.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use what the Owner's Manual calls for which is 75W-90 and almost certainly GL-5 spec.

It's probably safe to use 75W-140 but that's going to be quite a bit thicker and may impact your fuel economy and generate additional heat in the differential.

Who knows best, the dealer or the manufacturer?  Your choice.